# how to make a cross domain request that isnt forgeable

Tags: javascript, security, cross-domain, csrf

I need to get some data from `Site B` into `Site A`'s server side. In order to make the request to `Site B` to retrieve the data, there are cookies associated with `Site B`'s domain which need to be present. I assume I therefore need to do this in javascript with JSONP?

My ideas was to use JavaScript to make the request to `B` and then capture the result and stick it a cookie on `A`s domain such that subsequent requests to `A` would carry the cookie with the returned data (it doesnt matter that it takes two requests to `A` to get the information to `A`'s serverside). This would work fine, except its completely hackable.

The data itself isn't secret but I need to prevent request forgery or people on `Site A` calling the JSONP callback function manually, or setting the `A` cookie manually with stolen or otherwise faked data. Also, is there any other loophole for hacking? This would also need preventing!

The only way I can think of doing this is:

`Site A` generates a random token and stores it in the session. It then appends this token to the querystring of the JSONP request to `Site B`. `Site B` then responds but encrypts the usual data along with the token using digital signing. `Site A` then sticks this value in a cookie on `A`. In the next request to `A`, `A`s server side can capture the cookie, get the value, decrypt it, check the token and if it matches the value in the session, trust the rest of the data.

Does this sound sensible? Is there an easier way? My goal is to reduce the complexity at `A`s end.

Thanks

Comment: Are you in control of both sites?  i.e. can you do code changes in both domains?

Comment: Sounds like you just reinvented public key cryptography!  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#A_postal_analogy

Comment: @bdares no i didn't, because that still doesnt prevent forgery. whats to stop me stealing someone elses encrypted repsonse and using it myself?

Comment: @steve `Site A` is a customer site wanting to use my service `Site B`.  Yes their code can be changed but I need them to have to do as little work as possible

Comment: Any javascript ajax request you send from the client can be forged becuase the javascript source can be read/copied/modified

Comment: @Willem I know this, hence my question.

Comment: then don't think of it as sites (and requesting data with js or html requests) but create another data link, a secured webservice for example.

Answer (score 1):

The way to avoid it being hackable is to have the sites communicate with each other directly, rather than using client-side JavaScript.  Write a small light-weight REST API which allows the data to be transferred behind the scenes, server to server.

When linking to Site A, include an authentication token in the URL which can then be checked using the behind-the-scenes call to Site B.  This call can transfer any additional required information.  The token should probably be IP-bound, and expire after use.  Upon success, you can set up your cookie information in Site A, to avoid the need for further round trips.

Comment: that would be ideal, but what about the cookies for `Site B` stored in the user's browser?

Comment: Added more.  You can't get to the cookies of different domains for security reasons.

Comment: what do you mean "when linking to Site A"? also, JSONP requests will transfer cookies

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of JSONP transferring cookies?  Are you using an iFrame?  I presume at some point you link from Site B to Site A - or are your users just going to Site A independently?

Comment: well it uses a script tag, so it will send the cookies the same as any other request, its not ajax/xhr. Site A will be used independently

Comment: What if the user hasn't been to Site B on the device or in the browser  he's using (and therefore doesn't have the cookie)?  Will it redirect him to Site B?

Comment: No. I guess you were going to say "when when you link there, it can take you back with the token as per the comment above" well yes, that could work, except there are many `Site A`s, so then youre back to the same problem with `Site A'`. I tried to keep the question simple ;)

Comment: Do your users authenticate into Site B to get their 'master cookie'?  If so, you might want to consider implementing an OpenID provider for the other sites to use.

Comment: @Steve i could, but thats far too much faffing for `A` unfortunately. It needs to be ultra, ultra lightweight :(

Comment: also its not just auth, theres other data that comes back

Comment: Yeah, but once you've got an trusted session, you can use the afore-mentioned method to transfer further data without worry.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) to communicate between the domains. With it you have two javascript Programs, one on the consumers domain, and one on the providers, which can assert the domain of the consumer. Both these Programs can interact with the user, and the user can authenticate itself to both parties. With the providers Program knowing who the user is, and knowing who the consumer is, the provider can pass whatever data it wants to the consumer.

This is what big companies like Twitter, Disqus and LinkedIn use for their API's.